# Blogs to follow for programmers working on Telecom domain (Mobile/Smart Phones especially)

Tags: mobile, blogs, telecommunication

One per post will be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485092/recommended-mobile-both-application-and-web-development-blogs) are:

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/
http://www.mobilephonedevelopment.com/
http://blog.symbian.org/
http://justanapplication.wordpress.com/
http://www.mobileindustryreview.com/

Answer (score 1):

A collection of Telco related blogs can be found at [No Jitter](http://www.nojitter.com)